# Cannot manage azure purchase domain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

i accidentally deleted azure app service -web apps. The custom domain (purchase on azure) associated with deleted app cannot be assign to newly created web apps. I got following error:

"A records were found pointing to the following IP addresses: XXX.XX.XXX.XX, XXX.XXX.XXX.XX. Please create an A record pointing to the following IP address: XX.XX.XX.1XX No TXT records were found. Please create a TXT record pointing from .com to

How can i manage azure domain if app pointing to that domain is deleted? I am unable to change A record and CNAME of the domain. I cannot find link to domain management page nor "Advanced Management" . I have found link for domain management " https://dcc.secureserver.net/manage/" but i have no idea about my Username or Customer # and password as credential.

I need help

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to create a new  Azure web app (not with Free tier app service plan), and then you could find your purchased domains are listed in Custom domains blade.

[image]

And you could choose the purchased domain and to [manage it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-godaddy-custom-domain-name) via **Advanced management**.

[image]